# Set creation date from date in filename

Tags: bash, shell, automator

I'd like create an automator service to change the creation date of files from the date in the filename.

Filename :"2014-02-02 Lorem Ipsum.md" or "20190828719 Lorem Ipsum.md".

If there's a way to build both into one service that's amazing, but two would also work. Don't care about time, just date.

```sh
#Note: Filename = "2014-02-02 Lorem Ipsum.md"

$ BASENAME=$(basename $f)
$ TITLE=${BASENAME%.*}

$ echo "$TITLE" | cut -d" " -f1

2014-02-02
Lorem
Ipsum

$ #TOUCH - Something
```

I'm assuming I'll use some sort of `for f` `do` `done` to loop through all selected files.

Comment: You said you do not care about time but would be ok to modify time time creation, for example always set it to 00:00 or do you want to keep the original time creation?

Comment: In a PERFECT world, it would be this:  

#Case A: 2014-02-02   -   keep the original time creation  
#Case B: 201402021310  -  Update date and time  

The date is definitely the most important thing though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sed` to format the time and give it to `touch`:

```
for i in *.md; do 
   touch -d $(sed 's/[^0-9]//g;s/^\(.\{8\}\).*/\1/' <<< "$i") "$i"
done
```

The `sed` regex removes all none digit characters and takes only the first 8 remaining characters.

The `-d` option of `touch` set the modification time to the given date. This option might be GNU specific one and not available on macosx system.

On macosx, you may use the command `SetFile` (credits: [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/187673)):

```
for i in *.md; do 
   SetFile -d $(sed 's/[^0-9]//g;s/\(.\{4\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{2\}\).*/\1\/\2\/\3 00:00:00/' <<< "$i") "$i"
done
```

Comment: This almost works but it produces a strange timestamp. For this sample file is gives it a timestamp of Aug 14, 2020.

Is it because the date in the filename is YYYY-MM-DD?
Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: It works for both file `2014-02-02 Lorem Ipsum.md` and `20190828719 Lorem Ipsum.md` you listed. Can you please an example file where the command fails? If it fails for one of the file, please give the resulting string.

Comment: Hmmm.. I must be doing something wrong then. I've also tried running it in terminal to make it as simple as possible.

Here's a 20 second clip of my trying. Also, the -d is telling me it's an "illegal option", so when I take that off, it does modification date and goes to the Aug 14, 2020.

https://v.usetapes.com/LeWRhiRi1M

Comment: @DavidE The command I wrote is working on GNu/linux system, and may not work on your mac. I updated the answer with a possible solution

Comment: IT WORKS!!!

`for i in *.md; do  SetFile -d $(sed 's/[^0-9]//g;s/\(.\{4\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{2\}\).*/\2\/\3\/\1/' <<< "$i") "$i"; done`

Works to get the date. This is great.

For the sake of learning I was trying to modify it to also change hour and minute based on the last 4 characters of the timestamp (eg 201909022132). I'm having trouble. Here's what I have:

`for i in *.md; do  SetFile -d $(sed 's/[^0-9]//g;s/\(.\{4\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{2\}\).*/\2\/\3\/\1\/\4\/\5/' <<< "$i") "$i"; done`

Result: "ERROR: invalid date/time"

Any pointers? Thanks SO much.

Comment: @DavidE You can't use your last command since not all files contain the time. You would need to perform conditional formatting based on time being present or not.

Comment: I used modified version for my issue. Files naming as 2023-11-02 00.00.00 (1).ogg, 2023-11-01 00.00.00 (1) (1).ogg and so on. This is my version:

      `$ for i in /path/pathend/*.ogg; do
              DATESTR=$(sed 's/.*pathend\///g;s/^\(.\{19\}\).*/\1/;s/\./\:/g;' <<< "$i");
              touch -d "$DATESTR" "$i";
          done`

Thanks oliv.